# Kernel of Fredholm Operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Can we say something about the kernel of the Fredholm operator?

Is it necessarily non trivial? Somebody has proof/ counterexample?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator gives an example of an injective Fredholm operator.  (shift operator on $l^2$)

Comment: Oh, I missed it. Thanks